# ffmpeg extract all audio channels

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Is there a way in `ffmpeg` to extract all audio channels giving each a separate name?

The problem is that I don't know in advance how many channels the input file is going to have.

This does splitting into two wav files:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i input.wav -filter_complex
"[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" -map "[left]"
left.wav -map "[right]" right.wav
```

What can be done if the input file contains 3, or 8 channels?
Ideally, I would like to have a way to convert `Nchannels.mp4` into `Nchannels_1.wav`, `Nchannels_2.wav`, ..., `Nchannels_N.wav`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this in multiple steps.

1. Get number of channels with `ffprobe`:

   ```sh
   ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=channels,channel_layout -of default=nw=1 input.wav
       channels=6
       channel_layout=5.1
   ```
2. (Optional) Refer to `ffmpeg -layouts` to get channel names so you know what to name the outputs; as in the example below.
3. Build `ffmpeg` command using results from `ffprobe`:

   ```sh
   ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR]" -map "[FL]" front_left.wav -map "[FR]" front_right.wav -map "[FC]" front_center.wav -map "[LFE]" low_frequency_effects.wav -map "[BL]" back_left.wav -map "[BR]" back_right.wav
   ```

Comment: Well in my case ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=channels,channel_layout -of default=nw=1 8ch.wav.  shows:
channels=8
channel_layout=unknown, so I am not sure how to map the result to ffmpeg parameters

Comment: @AlexanderF Refer to `ffmpeg -layouts` and choose the layout that you think is most likely.

Comment: This is a really good answer, and it works great for actual 5.1 audio. Any idea how to do this for Dolby Surround encoded in just 2 audio channels? By default ffmpeg just emits the two channels, rather than demuxing the audio into 3 or 4. Supposedly it can be done with GraphEdit, but that's Windows only. Still looking for a solution that works for Mac.

Comment: @larryy What info does ffmpeg show about the input file? You can use a pastebin site and provide a link in a comment.

Comment: @llogan Here's an ffprobe and attempted demux: [https://pastebin.com/NSQbiZAu](https://pastebin.com/NSQbiZAu). The test.ac3 file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XCtRedHKdkAtM4_A9JiN3L6AMKvoxxZw/view?usp=sharing). The resulting channel files have audio in the FL and FR channels, and nothing in any of the other channels.

Comment: @larryy You should ask a new question. Matrixed Dolby Surround (or whatever this is) isn't something I ever work with so I don't know.